# Why do I get error domain is not a suffix of localhost?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

I've read about origin policy etc and as I understand it you should put origin policiy domain on the client and on the server.

Ok lets say I have this code on `example.com` and I want to fetch info from the page `doyouknoweverything.doyouknoweverything.com/recordOfMyLife` with jQuery/ajax

```
<div id="sk">Loading...</div> 
<script>
document.domain = "{example.com}";
$( "#sk" ).load( "http://whatever.doyouknoweverything.com/recordOfMyLife" );
</script>
```

If I understand this correctly I can do like this in the php-file `whatever.doyouknoweverything.com/recordOfMyLife`:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Is this correct?

Why do I get error domain is not a suffix of localhost? I guess I don't understand and it is probably something very easy for you guys who have done this before...

Answer (score 1):

Change

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

to

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.yoursite.com");
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! If I have three domains, can I just do like header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.yoursite.com, www.yoursecondsite.com, www.yourthirdsite.com"); ?  One of my issue is: Why does not document.domain = "{example.com}"; work? Can you give an example how to achieve what I want? Basically just to fetch some content from server and client.